# Can I drill a hole in a reinforced concreete with an impact driller?

Tags: drill, hanging

I am wondering wether I can drill in reinforced concrete 5-6mm(1/4”) diameter wholes and 30-40mm depth with my Bosch GSB-1080-LI-2, which is almost the same like GSB-120-LI?

Comment: The Reinforced part of Reinforced Concrete is rebars INSIDE the concrete. If you don't hit the rebars, it's just plain old concrete.

Answer (score 2):

After searching and asking myself whether this is possible, today I’ve decided to try.

Starting with full batteries and brand new 2 bits: 1. 3mm Bosch for concrete, and 2. 5mm Alpen for concrete, I have made 5 holes each 5mm wide and 35mm deep.

Settings were impact enabled, lowest speed (1(of 2) and 1 (of 20)).

It took around 4-5 minutes per hole with the 3mm, and then 1-2 minute with the 5mm bit.

Of course rotary hammer and SDS bits would be way easier and faster but even with this very small device I did my job.

Comment: Most times for a small one time job a better more expensive tool might be nice but not worth it, if the tool you do have can do the job, if slower.